Memoir header marks are blank when page style is changed within the document
I copied from the Memoir documentation some very simple and working code to modify headings. It seems like \rightmark and \leftmark fail to resolve if the page style is set temporarily or changed in the middle of the document.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\copypagestyle{headings2}{headings}
\addtopsmarks{headings2}{}{
  % changed left to both
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
}
\makeatother

\makeoddhead{headings2}{\thepage}{\rightmark}{}

%\pagestyle{headings2} Setting the page style here works

\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{headings2} Setting the page style here works
\chapter{Foo}
% Setting the style here successfully moves the page number
% But the chapter mark is blank
%\pagestyle{headings2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
% Same issue when setting the page style temporarily
%\thispagestyle{headings2} 
\lipsum[11-20]

\end{document}

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding how this is meant to work?
If it matters, I am using LuaLaTeX on Windows MiKTeX.

well sure, the new \createmark command is inside the pagestyle definition, and if you issue that after the \chapter command, \chapter will use the old \chaptermark. Do simply \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ } directly in the preamble.

Wouldn't that also apply the change to the \leftmark and \rightmark in the other pagestyle? The whole point here is whether it's possible to use \thispagestyle to temporarily change the header/footer, where the temporary pagestyle is one that includes \rightmark or \leftmark (and where those marks might be defined differently than for the previous pagestyle).

If it helps to understand why I would even want to do this, I encountered this behavior because the mainmatter of my project consists of sheet music included with pdfpages, and \includepdf sets the page style separately for each included pdf page. When I set pagecommand=\thispagestyle{mystyle}, I was surprised to find that the header fields were blank.
Now that I understand the behavior I can work around it by also including a \pagestyle command at the beginning of \mainmatter, but I find it surprising since I did not need to do this with the KOMA headings package.

you should distinguish between storing the data and using them. If you want to use sometimes the rightmark, then store it always but adapt the page styles so that is uses it only sometimes.  And at best store the mark with as less formatting as possible. Put the formatting into the pagestyle definition.

Welcome. It may help to distinguish even more things ;). Whether there is a particular mark at all. The content of the mark. Whether the mark is used. So think of it this way: you or the class you use or whatever set up all the marks you need in the preamble. Commands like \chapter etc. then typically put content into those marks or remove content from them. Settings such as the page style etc. then choose to use (and format) those marks or not. So you shouldn't (generally?) need to touch the marks directly in the document itself.
